# WITH Clause : Subquery Factoring using Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, with-clause

```
WITH dept_count AS (
  SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
  FROM   emp
  GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
       dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
FROM   emp e,
       dept_count dc
WHERE  e.deptno = dc.deptno;
```

How can we map the data retrieved from above query (**mean temporary table dept_count that got created due to the usage of WITH CLAUSE**) to the following java class?

My Java class is having the following attributes: employee_name, emp_dept_count.

Answer (score 0):

Use a native SQL query with a AliasToBeanResultTransformer ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html ).

Comment: Agree with usage of AliasToBeanResultTransformer for mapping data from pre defined entities (existing tables) to user defined java classes. But, in the above query, we are getting data from a temporary table (dept_count using WITH clause) where we cant add this to createCriteria of a session. Finally, is there any way to map the data from a temporary table (not an existing table) to a java class using hibernate?

Comment: No criteria, but native SQL. Just do createSqlQuery(..) with the Sql string you have, set the ResultTransfptmer and do list().